# MS SQL Server: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Action](
[ActionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ActionType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Initiator] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Action] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ActionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Code I try to execute:

```
create trigger delete_on_titles on titles
after delete
as
    begin
        insert into Action (ActionType, Initiator, Date) values ('Add', USER_NAME(), getdate());

        declare @id int = @@identity;
        insert into Old_titles select * from deleted
        update Old_titles set ActionId = @id where ActionId is null
    end
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure delete_on_titles, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 2]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

at the line `"insert into Action (ActionType, Initiator, Date) values ('Add', USER_NAME(), getdate());"`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**
Thanks to @Larnu. Yes, the problem was in the line:

```
insert into Old_titles select * from deleted
```

I changed it to:

```
insert into Old_titles (
title_id, title, type, pub_id, price, 
advance, royalty, ytd_sales, notes, pubdate) 
select * from deleted
```

where `title_id, title, type, pub_id, price, advance, royalty, ytd_sales, notes, pubdate` are columns of the table `deleted`, and it works.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's that line? I suspect it's `insert into Old_titles select * from deleted` as you omitted the column list twice.

Comment: Aside... consider replacing `@@identity` with `scope_identity()` instead. If the Action table has an insert trigger on it the result of `@@identity` may not be what you're expecting.

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ Using bad, lazy coding practices. An insert statement should always include a column list. `... values ('Add', USER_NAME(),` You wrote a **DELETE** trigger - is that really correct for your logging message?

Comment: `insert` followed by `update` is just silly, just insert it right the first time